# Real Business Cycle

Tags: macroeconomics

Could someone give me some suggestions or some possible papers to look at in order to improve upon RBC theory to explain the recent 2008 financial crisis?

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/what-have-been-the-main-developments-in-macroeconomics-and-financial-economics-s